# Hover zoom behavior not working as I expected on img tag inside span tag

Tags: html, css

When I zoom into the top image it shows the bottom image at the same time but when I zoom the bottom image it shows only the same image which is the behavior that I want.

How to make the image above work the same as the image below?

```css
img {
    width: 3.3125em;
    height: 3.3125em;
    display: block;
    postion: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 21.875em;
    height: 21.875em;
    margin-top: -9.4375em;
    margin-left: -9.4375em;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 150px;
}

span {
    text-align: right; 
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span > span {
    position: relative;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 3.5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>

<div>

<ul class="materials">
 <li class="item">
  
    <span><span><img  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545873692-64145c8c42ed?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80" alt="Safran"></span></span>
<span>Gold</span>
  
 </li>

 <li class="item">
  
    <span><span><img  src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/1stchoice/1stchoice1707/1stchoice170700075/82991692-silver-grey-background-texture-grunge.jpg" alt="Safran"></span></span>
<span>Silver</span>
  
 </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that you can solve this question with only html and css, please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some `z-index` property to the hovered object. This makes the hovered object overlay the other by changing its positioning on the z-axis ("three dimensional").

Note that there was a bug in your `position` property of `img`. Fixed below.

```css
img {
    width: 3.3125em;
    height: 3.3125em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 21.875em;
    height: 21.875em;
    margin-top: -9.4375em;
    margin-left: -9.4375em;
    z-index: 1
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 150px;
}

span {
    text-align: right; 
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span > span {
    position: relative;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 3.5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>

<div>

<ul class="materials">
 <li class="item">
  
    <span><span><img  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545873692-64145c8c42ed?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80" alt="Safran"></span></span>
<span>Gold</span>
  
 </li>

 <li class="item">
  
    <span><span><img  src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/1stchoice/1stchoice1707/1stchoice170700075/82991692-silver-grey-background-texture-grunge.jpg" alt="Safran"></span></span>
<span>Silver</span>
  
 </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with `z-index` the problem is when you move the cursor outside the zoomed circle it shown immediately the silver circle and it doesn't look good, I want exactly the same behavior like silver circle

Comment: This  won't be possible without JS.The problem is that as soon as you leave the zoomed object the browser takes its initial size which is why the other one "overlaps" straight away